# Configure CLion to handle gtk_builder signals

Tags: c, cmake, gtk, clion, glade

I'm trying to connect a signal of a GTK widget made using Glade with the [gtk_builder_connect_signals ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-connect-signals)
, As the the documentation says this function requires the program to be compiled with `-Wl,--export-dynamic` Cflags and linked against `gmodule-export-2.0`.
compiling this code with the following command works successfully.

```
/*Command : gcc sample.c  -Wall -Wextra -Wl,--export-dynamic `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-export-2.0` -o sample */
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void add_etdnts(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer data){
   g_print("function succefully called");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 GtkBuilder *builder;

 GtkWidget *window;
 GError *error = NULL;

 gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

 builder = gtk_builder_new();

 if(! gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder,"style.glade",&error)){
    g_warning("%s",error->message);
    g_free(error);
    return  1;
 }
 window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"window"));
 gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder,NULL);

 g_object_unref( G_OBJECT( builder ) );

 gtk_widget_show( window );

 //Start main loop
 gtk_main();
 return 0;
}
```

> But for some reason i can't compile it under the CLion IDE(LINUX) even after adding the following lines to "CMakeLists.txt"

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(UI)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
find_package(GTK 3 REQUIRED gtk)

if(GTK3_FOUND)
 include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 set(SOURCE_FILES main.c main.h )
 add_executable(UI ${SOURCE_FILES})
 target_link_libraries(UI ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})

    ############# something is wrong here ##############
 set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0")
 set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0")
endif()
```

[Errors interpreted on building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAZI9.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0")
```

This does not make sense: you've set pkg-config as your c++ compiler.

Use the [pkg-config support](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html) in CMake:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0)
...
target_link_libraries(UI ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(UI ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```